# What is the most appropriate HTTP status code for flooding?

Tags: http, response, http-status-codes

Which HTTP status is the most appropriate when user performs actions too fast (floods) or spams it? I believe it's one of 4XX family, but which one?

Comment: http://httpstatusdogs.com/429-too-many-requests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is 429 Too Many Requests

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#429

Comment: Wow, what is this massive downvote for? Is this 429 status official? I have looked at the list of statuses where 429 was not present. Shall I use it today?

Comment: Then you are looking at the wrong list. The official one is at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml and it includes 429.

Comment: I thought this is the official list of safe statuses: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: No. 1) The list of status codes is extensible, thus there's a registry. And furthermore, RFC 2616 it obsolete, you need to read RFCs 7230..5 instead (in this case http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#status.codes in particular)